# wpf TreeView HierarchicalDataTemplate related

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, treeview

I have a question related to HierarchicalDataTemplate. Is it possible to keep adding HierarchicalDataTemplate via code or there is no way to do that. I'm asking this because in my case later i don't know if i will need more child nodes than these i have now.

below you can see my treeview:

```
<TreeView Background="#FFF0F0F0" BorderBrush="#FFE5E2DB" IsEnabled="{Binding isAllesEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding LijstRechten, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="dgStamOverzichtGebruikerRechten" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <!-- Top Level -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Content="{Binding naam}" />

            <!-- 1st Child Level -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Content="{Binding naam}" />

                    <!-- 2nd Child Level -->
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Content="{Binding naam}" />

                            <!-- 3rd Child Level -->
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Content="{Binding naam}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded"  Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
            <!--<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding isSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <EventSetter Event="Selected" Handler="TreeViewSelectedItemChanged" />-->
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  your problem, assuming all the childs are of same type.. just define one `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in your window's resources `without any x:key` and put the `DataType` which is type of your Child object...Your whole tree will populate..

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{local:YourParentType}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Content="{Binding naam}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>


<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{local:YourChildType}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Childs}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}" Content="{Binding naam}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

here assuming local is the namespace (xmlns) in which your Child class is defined

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, i just cant understand the DataType part, im using a usercontrol and a viewmodel, do i have to add something to the xmlns part of my usercontrol?

Comment: DataType will be your ViewModel if all the child objects are of the same ViewModel

Comment: can you share the type of your child object and the namespace it is defined in?

Comment: Hi, sure i can provide those information, the namespace is MyProject.Settings and the objects im using are: clsTreeViewParent for the treeview itemssource and clsTreeViewChild for the HierarchicalDataTemplate itemssource. I have tried something but it doesnt work i did change DataType="{local:YourChildType}" to DataType="{x:Type vm:clsTreeViewParent}" where vm is the xmlns on my usercontrol, then the top node will show correctly but all the others are missing the reference and just show as MyProject.settings.clsTreeViewchilds.

Comment: hi, in this case since your parent and child are of two different type.. you will need two tempalates... i hope Child class i,e clsTreeViewChild will inturn have childs in it of same type..then you can refer to my updated answer

Comment: Hi, yes i realized that i had two different types so i just changed deleted the class clsTreeViewChild and keep the clsTreeViewParent, making the Child property as the same as the parent, in this way will work correctly. And even tho after look better at the code i really dont need a new class type for this! Will accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Was just looking for a way to set a single HierarchicalDataTemplate and DataTemplate definition to be used by multiple TreeViews bound to the same data types. Your answer was just what I needed! Thanks!