# C# WPF reach an object in ObservableCollection by binding a TreeViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeviewitem

Im working on a WPF project trying to get information from an ImpactElement-object. That object is inside a ObservableCollection called ElementList. This ElementList is located inside another ObservableCollection called ListOfCreatedStacks that holds objects of the Class Stack.

It only shows the toString from the element (ImpactElement) inside ElementList. I want the ImpactElements variable ElementMark to be shown from each elemnt in ElementList.

This is how it looks right now [One element added in the ElementList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eirFA.png)

I can create any numbers of Stack and inside each stack there´s a ElementList with different numbers of ImpactElement. [Two stacks with different amount of ImpactElements in the ElementList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQBL9.png)

From these pictures you can see that each ImpactElement from the ElementList is shown as "IMPACT_Visual_Stacker.Model.ImpactElement" but i want it to be the variable ElementMark that is inside ImpactElement Class.

Here´s the code from different Classes.

```
public class Controller
{
    public ObservableCollection<Stack> ListOfCreatedStacks { get { return listOfCreatedStacks; } set { listOfCreatedStacks = value; } }
}

public class Stack
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImpactElement> ElementList { get { return elementList; } set { elementList = value; } }
    public string Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
}

public class ImpactElement
{
    private string elementMark;
    private int id;
    private Vector3 sizeLWH;
    private Vector3 positionXYZ;
    private Vector3 rotationXYZ;
    private Mesh elementMesh;
}
```

Here´s the XAML part.

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCreatedStacks}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350, 200,0,0" Width="300">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem
                    Header="{Binding Id}"
                    IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"  Header="{Binding ElementMark}" IsExpanded="True">
                    </TreeViewItem>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

---

I've tried a solution from the other StackOverflow i got from Ed.
The result ends up with only adding a Hiearchy object insted of my "ImpactElement"-objects.

This is what the tested XAML looks like :

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCreatedStacks}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350, 200,0,0" Width="300">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCreatedStacks}">
                <TreeViewItem
                    Header="{Binding Id}"
                    IsExpanded="True">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type System:String}"
                                              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}">
                        <TreeViewItem
                            Header="{Binding ElementMark}"
                            IsExpanded="True">
                        </TreeViewItem>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Feels like a miss some easy part that i dont understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097338/wpf-treeview-hierarchicaldatatemplate-related

Comment: Thanks for reply Ed. That was a good answer in that question. Since i do not have the same child and parents and not Hierachy, i dont see how i can apply it?

Comment: Use a HierarchicalDataTemplate. If you can't modify that answer to your own needs, ask another question about the spot where you ran into trouble. If you're unwilling to try, I'm sorry but I can't help you.

Comment: Hi Ed. 
I've tried the solution from the answer you sent. I can't get it to work. I updated the orginal question. Do you see what i miss?

Comment: Why are you trying to nest `TreeViewItem` in a `ListView` instead of a `TreeView`?

Comment: grek40 thats a good question. I don´t really know. The only thing i got to work is a ListView. Could it be the ListView that is the problem?

Comment: I tryed to change the ListView to a TreeView, that worked, but still the same problem. I don´t reach the ElementList. It´s like the binding stops on ListOfCreatedStacks

Comment: @newToCSharp Now we're in business! I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

First, `Controller`, `ElementList`, and `ImpactElement` should probably be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You can find a million examples of that on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. It's simple, and you can get help here if you run into any snags.

What that will do is cause the UI to update if you change any bound property values on those objects while they're visible in the UI. The `ObservableCollection`s will notify the UI if you add or remove items, but they can't notify the UI if some property of one of items happens to change.

Second, `ImpactElement` has only private fields. Since the private fields were omitted on the other classes, I'm guessing this was just an oversight when you copied the code. But you can only bind to public properties. Must be public, must be a property with a `get` and usually a `set`.

I'm hoping that you've assigned an instance of `Controller` to your `DataContext`. If you didn't, the tree won't populate.

I found WPF's `TreeView` baffling at first, and I wasn't new to XAML when I first looked at it. Do a bunch of simple examples (and come here for help if you need it), don't just paste in the XAML I gave you. It'll snap into focus.

Finally, you did a lot of things in your XAML that weren't done in the example. I don't know why you did those things, but you can't just go doing stuff at random. It doesn't work well. But as I said the learning curve on this one is tough, so no harm done.

So here's the XAML:

```
<TreeView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfCreatedStacks}" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="350, 200,0,0"
    Width="300">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style 
            TargetType="TreeViewItem" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TreeViewItem}}"
            >
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            DataType="{x:Type local:Stack}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementList}"
            >
            <Label Content="{Binding Id}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
                    DataType="{x:Type local:ImpactElement}"
                    >
                    <Label Content="{Binding ElementMark}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

So the TreeView's ItemsSource is `ListOfCreatedStacks`.

We give the `TreeView` an `ItemContainerStyle` which will apply to every `TreeViewItem` in the tree. We only do that so we can set `IsExpanded`. There's no other way to get to the `TreeViewItem`s. We *could* also give the top-level item template an `ItemContainerStyle` of its own, which would only affect its children, if we wanted to do something different with those. But we don't need to.

And we give the `TreeView` an `ItemTemplate`. That is how we show a `TreeViewItem` how to display one of the `TreeView`'s children. When you look at the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, it's a bit like a `TreeView`: It's got an `ItemsSource`, which we bind to a property of `Stack` which contains the *children* of the `Stack`. It has an `ItemTemplate` for its own children. It *could*, as I said, have an `ItemContainerStyle`, but we'll just let it inherit the one we set on the `TreeView`.

It's recursive: A tree node is very much like a whole tree.

If you don't give a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` an `ItemTemplate` of its own, the `TreeViewItems` it applies to will just use that one as the template for their own children, and the children will do the same. If you gave `ImpactElement` a child collection of `ImpactElement`s, the tree could be two dozen levels deep without making a single change in the XAML above.

Any `DataTemplate` or `HierarchicalDataTempate` can have a `DataType` property. That is the type of viewmodel item being displayed by the template. I don't know where you got `System:String` from.

In this particular case<sup>1</sup>, `DataType` serves no purpose but to help you keep things straight when you're editing the XAML: It reminds you which template at which level of recursion applies to which collection item, and he's Intellisense help you out as well.

Finally, we have the content of the `HierarchicalDataTempate`:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Id}" />
```

That could be any single XAML element, but it could be a `Grid` or a `StackPanel` containing a whole UI if you wanted. You can put anything in there. You could put a whole different `TreeView` in there.

Lastly, you should learn to do layout with `StackPanel` and `Grid` columns and rows. This margin business is a nightmare if you want to rearrange anything. I presume you're using the Design mode in VS? All I use that for is to preview what I've done by hand in the XAML. Properly done, in XAML layout everything's positioned relative to its parent and siblings. Maybe it has a fixed width and/or height, usually a small margin -- single digits -- just to create space between neighbors, not for absolute positioning. Once you get used to it, it's a really nice way to work with stuff. A lot like HTML.

---

<sup>1</sup> For the other uses of the `DataType` property of a `DataTemplate` or `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, see ["implicit datatemplates"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176092/424129), and here's a [more complicated example for doing it with treeview items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15344099/424129). If you're already struggling to digest all this, don't go look at that stuff, just focus on the case I gave you above. That's more than enough. Data templates are a learning curve, and adding recursion just makes everything weirder.